# How to replace text inside the non-standard <nobr>

Tags: html, jquery, dom, adobe-captivate

Adobe is using an ancient and nonstandard nobr HTML tag in Adobe Captivate 2019. The absence of IDs doesn't help either.

...

```
<div class="tocSlideTitleHeading" style="height: 14px; width: 55px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" tabindex="-1">
<nobr>Slide Title</nobr>
</div>
```

...

I need to replace the static text "Slide Title" inside the nobr tag with something more appropriate to the task (or better yet - replace the entire nobr tag along with its content.  I don't want to replace nobr globally quite yet, just this instance for now.)

Thanks

Comment: Changing it onclick, or onload?  what is the trigger?

Comment: You should be able to select any arbitrary custom element. Like what @mathius1 said, what trigger should be listened to before replacing the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be replaced upon loading the document, this would do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".tocSlideTitleHeading nobr").replaceWith("<span>New Title</span>");
});
```

And if you would like to just replace the text inside the `<nobr>` tag instead of replacing it completely:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tocSlideTitleHeading nobr").text("New Title");
 });
```